# On click of a button,obtain the selected value from a checkbox list which is present in a div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a aspx page in which there is a div. On click of a button the div is being displayed. The div contains a list of checkboxes and an "apply" button. If some values in the list are checked and the apply button is clicked, the selected value must be added to the page. This is my requirement.
 But what happens is that, on click of the "apply" button, page load happens and the list of checkboxes is being cleared. Because of this, i am not able identify the selected items. How to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

```
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

int assp=0;
for(int itest=0;itest<chkAvailablelist.Items.Count;itest++)
{
    if(chkAvailablelist.Items[itest].Selected)
        {
            assp=1;
    }
}
```

In dubug mode, the chkAvailablelist is being shown as empty

Comment: You want the values on the clientside or the serverside? Do you want that postback to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Has every single checkbox got a `checked = false` when checking on the server (after the button click)?

If so you've probably got something in your page_Load() which is clearing them.

But you need to ask yourself; do you actually want the postback to happen or do you need to check them via javascript?

On another note is viewstate enabled?

Comment: Hi..during page load there is no such code that clears it. The entire list is empty. There are no checkboxes inside the list.

Comment: @epascarello, Yes i want the postback to happen I want the values in server side

Comment: Do the checkboxes have the attribute `runat='server'`?

Comment: yes , it does... <asp:checkboxlist EnableViewState="True" id="chkAvailablelist" runat="server"></asp:checkboxlist>

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using to access the checkboxes server side?

Answer (score 0):

If the checkboxes don't exist when the page is rendered, does the server know about them when the postback happens?  Could clicking the button un-hide the DIV, rather than JS?  That way the server would know about them.

OR

If Page_Load is clearing the checkboxes, is it because you aren't checking for page.ispostback?

I'm sorry if these answers are too basic but some of your description sounds like some basic mistakes I know I've made in the past.  :)

Comment: Hi steve..i am checking for postback, the postback event is happening..I have declared my button like this:-

Comment: <asp:button id="Button3"  runat="server" CssClass="MainButton" Width="92px" Height="26px" Text="Apply" ></asp:button>

Comment: during page load, if try the below code, i can see that the list is empty

Comment: for(int itest=0;itest<chkAvailablelist.Items.Count;itest++)
//    {
//     if(chkAvailablelist.Items[itest].Selected)
//     {
//       assp=1;
//     }
//    }

Comment: I'm thinking that chkAvailableList is databound in page_load, right?  And that's only when it's *not* a postback, right?

How is chkAvailableList hidden?  Is it's style display:none, then js unhides it?  

I was advocating a postback on the unhide button, then ASP.NET will know all about the cbl when the apply button is clicked.